# Rollback SourceSafe by comment

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-sourcesafe

I work with VSS (SourceSafe) and wonder how to obtain a list of files checked in with a comment (say, all files with the comment "my instable version") and rollback those changes?

Comment: Please stop tagging this as `c#` or `.net`. It has nothing to do with it. Unless you want to do it via code, but then I would expect you to say that much. Thank you.

Comment: @leppie who follow visual-sourcesave tag? 2-3 people? nobody will answer me! Let me alone! I Use it in a .NET project

Comment: With that thinking, add `java` and `php` too!

Comment: When I saw such questions, I cannot stop thinking VSS is a very bad product (no mentioning its very low reliability). I'm quite sure your context can't allow you to change, but you should really take a look at SVN or GIT (the one I know but there are plenty of others) source repositories. VSS may have been good in the late 90s, but isn't suited for 2010's dev requirements. Moreover, alternatives are free, while VSS is commercial. Your question let me think you need an efficient branching tool. VSS is not efficient in this way. Hope you can change !

Comment: Java and PHP does not work with SourceSafe ( why do you don't remove the Visual Studio tag as well???

Comment: Visual Source safe work with any kind of file/project, even with java php or assembler files. Anyways, @Leppie is right this is an issue with VSS, not with .Net. I understand you will have difficulties to find support with only vss tag, but you will risk to have the question closed if it's not properly written. I would suggest you to put actual tags, and also try on MS forums.

Comment: I understand, Steve, but if I target only VSS tag, nobody will answer me.

Comment: @serhio: I came to this question because of the .net tag. I cannot help you with visual source safe. You just wasted my time because of the incorrect tag(s). If someone is interested in answering VSS questions, then he will follow that tag.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to automatically rollback changes by comment, but you can create a Report from SourceSafe history. This report is really just a text file, but it contains details about every checkin, including the label, and the lines changed about that checkin.

You create a Report from the History dialog (you get it from Tools->History or Ctrl+H), there's a button above help which you press. Don't forget to check Recursive for the history, otherwise the Report won't contain checkin from the subfolders.

Oh, and btw I got here by following the visual-sourcesafe tag :)